# order date with mysql

Tags: mysql, date

How can I order date on mysql? I have tried this:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%d/%m/%Y') Date
FROM 
   date_time
ORDER BY Date;
```

but not work fine

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

order it by `date_time` because `DATE` (*an alias*) is already `VARCHAR`

```
ORDER BY date_time;
```

Comment: @Jjreina you're welcome :D hope it's clear why your original `ORDER BY` won't work